# In java the JFileDialog box will not appear multiple times

Tags: java, jfilechooser

On my computer this block of code will only show the JFileChooser once instead of multiple times. (Im on a Mac)

I need to be able to show the dialog multiple times.

```
public class FileManager {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        showDirectoryDialog();
        System.out.println("BLOCKING");
        showDirectoryDialog();
        System.out.println("BLOCKING");
    }

    public static File showDirectoryDialog() {
        System.out.println("Creating dialog");
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        System.out.println("Dialog done");
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            return f;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
This does work if I create a static instance of JFileChooser and persist it.

does anyone know why this behaviour exists?

EDIT2:
I am using OSX 10.9.4
And I checked to make sure the second dialog box was not at the behind any other programs.
(unless they hid it behind the desktop lol)

Comment: It's working just fine for me on Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you for running that for me.  :)
For some reason Mac has a big issue with File Dialogs
I had a similar issue in python

Comment: Guess nobody at apple can imagine a use-case for two file-dialogs of the same application to be open at the same time. Also I as user normally like them one-by-one.

Comment: This is not open at the same time...
This is using one,  then in the same thread some time later using another

Comment: Are you saying you want these two dialogs to popup at the same time (in this test program)?  Or are you saying that, on a mac, the second one does not appear after the first one is dismissed?

Comment: The second of the two. The second dialog box does not appear after the first one is dismissed.

Unless I have a static singleton of the Dialog box and use that same instance for both